# Writing IF Condition with 2 or more columns in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Below is the data I have..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWBae.png)

> [image]

In the above picture

1. If Column"E" is empty then I should get status(Column "H") as "Scheduled".
2. If Column"G" is empty then I should get status(Column "H") as "In
   Progress".
3. If Column"E, F, G" are filled with some data then status(Column "H")
   as "succeeded"

.

I have used the below logic

> =IF(E7=" ","scheduled",IF(G7=" ","In Progress",IF(OR(EXACT(E7, G7),(G7>E7),(E7>G7)),  "Succeeded","In Progress")))

But it is not satisfying my 2nd condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
=IF(AND(E7<>"",F7<>"",G7<>""),"Succeeded",IF(E7="","Scheduled",IF(G7="","In Progress","F is Blank")))
```

Paste it in H7

Comment: Hi Maddy, Thanks for your response. But its not giving correct result. It's giving "Succeeded" as result.

Comment: Hi Maddy, It's satisfying my 2nd and 3rd condition but missing 1st condition.

Comment: what are the values in E,F G column?

Comment: The data is dates. You can see the picture I have attached in my question

Comment: its working fine here ..if E7 is empty then its giving **Schuduled** status

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
  =IF(ISBLANK(E7),"Scheduled",IF(ISBLANK(G7),"In Progress",IF(SUMPRODUCT((E7<>"")*(F7<>"")*(G7<>"")),"Succeeded","I don't know what output you would like to see in case of 'ELSE' situation ")))
```